# PHP regex preg_split - split by largest group only

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have the following regex

```
((\$|(\\\[)).*?(\$|(\\\])))
```

which should capture everything between `$$` and `\[\]` and I tested it on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it's working.

PHP variant is (doubled backslashes)

```
((\$|(\\\\\[)).*?(\$|(\\\\\])))
```

and I would like to split my text based on that regex. How can I tell that it uses just the first (and largest group) and not these small ones?

```
preg_split('/((\$|(\\\\\[)).*?(\$|(\\\\\])))/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

So for text `This is my $test$ for something.` I should get an array

```
[0] => This is my 
[1] => $test$
[2] =>  for something.
```

But I get

```
[0] => This is my 
[1] => $test$
[2] => $
[3] => 
[4] => $
[5] =>  for something.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need something like this:

```
$text = 'This is my $test$ for \[something\] new!';
print_r(preg_split('/(\$.*?\$|\\\\\[.*?\\\\\])/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is my 
    [1] => $test$
    [2] =>  for 
    [3] => \[something\]
    [4] =>  new!
)
```

---

IMHO, your regex is (probably) wrong. It would fail for texts like `Hello $there\]`. If you need to capture texts between two `$`s and a pair of `\[` and `\]`, then you need the regexp like:

```
          <-------------> Match text between \[ and \]
/(\$.*?\$|\\\\\[.*?\\\\\])/
  <----->   Match text between dollars
```